# Finding the the element-wise ratio of two column vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following equation:

$\mathbf{C} \mathbf{s_{+}} = \mathbf{s_{-}}$

where $\mathbf{C}$ is a $N \times N$ matrix of full rank, and  $ \mathbf{s_{+}}$ and $ \mathbf{s_{-}}$ are column vectors.

I want to find the element-wise ratio of the two column vectors,  $\mathbf{s_{+}(i)}/\mathbf{s_{-}(i)}, \quad \forall i = 1, \ldots,N$. Also, $\mathbf{s_{+}}=[s_{1+}, s_{2+}, s_{3+}, 0, 0, 0]^T$, and $\mathbf{s_{-}}=[s_{1-}, s_{2-}, s_{3-}, s_{4-}, s_{5-},s_{6-}]^T$. Any ideas?

Comment: I looked into Hadamard product (to take the ratio of the two vectors) but it didn't get me far. Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

Let $e_i$ be the vector $[0,...,0,1,0,...,0]^T$ with 1 only on $i$th position.

Then $Diag(a)=\sum_i e_ie_i^Ta$. So elementwise $b/a$ is $Diag(a)^{-1}b$.

So it is $Diag(s_{-})^{-1}s_{+}=(\sum_i e_i e_i^T s_{-})^{-1} s_{+}$

Comment: Thanks, but I should probably rephrase the problem: I am looking for the ratio as a function of matrix $\mathbf{C}$. My unknowns are the elements $\mathbf{s_{+}(i)}/\mathbf{s_{-}(i)}$.